# Singular Value Decomposition and lower-rank projection

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, svd

Suppose we have matrices $Q, K, V \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $P = QK^\top$ is of rank $k$. We want to prove that there exist two matrices $C, D \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n}$ such that $PV = Q(CK)^\top DV$.

I think singular value decomposition can help, but after writing down the SVD of $P$ I don't know how to proceed.

Anyone share some hint?

Comment: I see no $D$ in the equation.

Comment: Sorry --- edited.

Comment: Shouldn't they have some required property?

Comment: Sorry but I don't think the original question included any property other than the dimensions and the rank of $P$.

Comment: Just in that case you have way more freedom than you need, I think. But I also think some assumption is needed on $Q$ and $K$, e.g. that they're invertible. If they aren't invertible then this might potentially be impossible.

Comment: I'm sorry I was too tired when typing this question, and I forgot another important line... Now the question is complete.

Comment: Oh. In that case, it suffices to have $C^T D$ be any projection onto the row space of $P$. One way to do that is to find an orthonormal basis of the row space of $P$, then put those in as columns of $D$, and then have $C=D$.

Comment: Can you briefly explain why that works though? I am having a hard time understanding it...

Comment: So the basic point is that $C^T D$ is forced to have rank at most k by the shape of the matrices it was built from. Thus in order for $Q K^T C^T D$ to have the same range as $Q K^T$, $C^T D$ must map $\mathbb{R}^n$ onto the row space of $Q K^T$. This is because the row space of a matrix $A$ with rank $r$ is the only $r$-dimensional subspace such that the restriction of $A$ to such a subspace has the same range as $A$. This is related to the "fundamental subspaces theorem" (in Strang's terminology) as well as the rank-nullity theorem.